# when running server, django always displays error

Tags: python, django

im only learnin python and django, i tried running server but only it shows error that says

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\theta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-             packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 717, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'app_advertisements' from      '  C:\\Users\\theta\\PycharmProjects\\advertisements\\app_advertisements\\__init__.py'
>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

urls.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
     from django.urls import path, include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('app_advertisements')),
]
```

and an app\urls.py

```
   from django.urls import path
    from .views import index

     urlpatterns = [
        path('user/', index),
]
```

------------------EDIT-------------

i just created new project, and copied almost every line of code,
and it somehow works
i dont know how but i dont really care as long as it works

Comment: you have `include('app_advertisements')` and then the error is telling you the problem: _"The included URLconf '<module 'app_advertisements' from '  C:\\Users\\theta\\PycharmProjects\\advertisements\\app_advertisements\\_\_init\_\_.py' does not appear to have any patterns in it"_

Comment: when you say _"and an app\urls.py"_ in the question do you mean that is `app_advertisements/urls.py` ?  In that case in the other file you should `path('', include('app_advertisements.urls'))`